# Backing field of type ILogger but the injected param of type ILogger<T>

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

The .Net Core logging framework was designed to be used with dependency injection. For example, if you want to add logging to a class named `MyClass` you need to add an `ILogger<MyClass>` parameter to the class’ constructor:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

## Question

The above coding pattern are very common (IMHO) where the backing field of type `ILogger` while the injected parameter of type `ILogger<T>`.

Why don't we use the backing field of type `ILogger<MyClass>` instead of `ILogger`? Is there any difference?

Comment: If you want to be an expert at something, you need to be very good at the fundamentals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ILogger<T>` implements `ILogger`. That's why you can assign `ILogger<T>` to `ILogger` The XML comment for `ILogger<T>` is:

> Generally used to enable activation of a named ILogger from dependency injection.

This tells you that somewhere, some code needs the type to create a logger for you.

If you drill down into the code for `service.AddLogging()` there is an `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<>` getting added to `IServiceCollection`. `ILogger<T>` has a concrete implementation `Logger<T>`. `Logger<T>` gets the above mentioned `ILoggerFactory` injected and then calls `CreateLogger` passing in the displayname of type T. `LoggerFactory` then checks a cache of already created `Logger`s based on the `T` and return that from cache, adding it if it doesn't exist.

So basically, it adds no extra functionality but internally it boosts performance by storing an ILogger per type in a cache and handing it to you when needed. The `<T>` is needed because it gets used in the Dictionary/cache lookup

Answer (score 2):

`ILogger<T>` is defined as follows:

```
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
{
}
```

I found this code through "go to definition" in Visual Studio, but you can see the same in the now-archived repository [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs).

On that basis, my conclusion is that `ILogger<T>` provides an easy way to set the category of the generated logger, but doesn't actually change the functionality. Thus, I think using `ILogger` for the backing field is fine since `ILogger<T>` doesn't add any methods.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The `ILogger<T>` interface adds no additional methods or properties to the `ILogger` interface so you are free to choose whichever you prefer.

You can view the source code for each and the logging code below:

[ILogger code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILogger.cs)

[ILoggerOfT code](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/ILoggerOfT.cs)